# How to shift binary string based on the dynamic value - PHP

Tags: php, binary

I have a binary string of 336 in 0 and 1 form. I am getting a value from a variable. Let's say the string is 010101010001111 and variable value is 3, then I want a string like this: 111010101010001.

Is it possible? How can it be done in PHP?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Improved grammar and formatting.

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking. What is the connection/logic behind the binary string and the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do a bit of *bit* manipulation here,

```
$string = '010101010001111';
$decVal = bindec($string);
$variable = 3;
$result = decbin(($decVal >> $variable) | (($decVal << (strlen($string) - $variable)) & ~(~0 << strlen($string))));
echo $result;
```

Live Demo: [**https://3v4l.org/lSCLq**](https://3v4l.org/lSCLq)

The overall idea is like this:

1. Convert binary string to decimal value.

   ```
   $decVal = bindec($string); // 010101010001111 --> 10895
   ```
2. Right shift `$decVal` value by `$variable` positions.

   ```
   $decVal >> $variable  // 010101010001111 --> 000010101010001
   ```
3. Left shift `$decVal` value by `strlen($string) - $variable` positions

   ```
   $decVal << (strlen($string) - $variable) // 010101010001111 --> 010101010001111000000000000
   ```
4. `AND` the output of step# 3 with `...0000000000111111111111111`

   ```
   (($decVal << (strlen($string) - $variable)) & ~(~0 << strlen($string))) // 010101010001111000000000000 & ...0000000000111111111111111 --> ...0000000000111000000000000
   ```
5. `OR` the output of step# 2 and step# 4 to achieve the desired result

   ```
   ($decVal >> $variable) | (($decVal << (strlen($string) - $variable)) & ~(($decVal | ~0) << strlen($string))) // 000010101010001 | ...0000000000111000000000000--> 111010101010001
   ```
6. Finally, display the output of step# 5 in binary string representation.

   ```
   $result = decbin(...);
   echo $result;
   ```

Comment: Bundle of Thanx. Could you explain this ~(($decVal | ~0) << strlen($string))) from step 4

Comment: @HarisKhan, Let me explain a bit here, but before that - I would like to point out that I have changed `~(($decVal | ~0) << strlen($string))` to `~(~0 << strlen($string))` as `$decVal` is not required here.

Comment: @HarisKhan, Now the explanation; when you do `~0` you will get all `1`s i.e. `11111111....`, so `~0 << strlen($string)` will give you `...1111111000000000000000` and negation of the whole expression i.e. `~(~0 << strlen($string))` will be `...00000000111111111111111`. Finally, in step# 4 `AND` of `($decVal << (strlen($string) - $variable))` and `~(~0 << strlen($string))` will give you `...000111000000000000`. This value when gets `OR`ed with output of step# 2 gives the required result. I hope you understood now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
$num = "010101010001111";
$shiftCount = 3;
$valueToReplace = 1;
echo substr(str_pad($num, strlen($num)+$shiftCount,$valueToReplace,STR_PAD_LEFT),0,-$shiftCount);
```

[str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) — Pad a string to a certain length with another string
[substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) — Return part of a string
[strlen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) — Get string length

> pad_type
>
> Optional argument pad_type can be **STR_PAD_RIGHT**, **STR_PAD_LEFT**, or
>   **STR_PAD_BOTH**. If pad_type is not specified it is assumed to be
>   **STR_PAD_RIGHT**.

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abf5b07157c13deba99ad1ad3f7a58a234e55d61)